# <servlet-name> inside <filter-mapping> of web.xml, what does this mean?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml

I am starting to learn Struts 2. I stumbled upon this code:

**web.xml**

```xml
...some other codes...

<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <display-name>MyFilter</display-name>
    <filter-class>com.xxx.yyy.zzz.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>MyAction</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
   <listener-class>com.xxx.yyy.StrutsListener</listener-class>
</listener> 

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyAction</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>paramName1param-name>
        <param-value>paramVal1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>paramName2</param-name>
        <param-value>paramVal2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

...some other codes...
```

My question is in this part

```xml
 <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>MyAction</servlet-name>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Why is it a servlet being mapped inside a `<filter-mapping>` tag? What does this kind of mapping imply? Also, what does `<listener>` do? Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried Google ?

> Why is it a servlet being mapped inside a tag? What does this kind of
>   mapping imply?

Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1039330

> what does `<listener>` do?

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1039300

Example: http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.in/2009/01/tomcat-context-listener-example.html

Comment: I tried googling but I find hard time defining my question in the search box. Keeps returning article that doesn't answer my questions. Those article answered my questions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bnrdo: Good to hear that. You are wel-come