# Set custom filter on Tomcat 8 using web.xml

Tags: java, cors, tomcat8

I want to enable CORS Tomcat 8 using this method (custom filter)
[Tomcat CORS filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386712/tomcat-cors-filter)

I'm confused on step making custom filter to be called in web.xml.

How to set the .java file? Where is the directory of this file (SimpleCORSFilter)?

```
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
      chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define filter as [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846309/cors-filter-not-working-as-intended) connected to URL:

> ```
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>com.robin.filters.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
> </filter>
>
> <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
>     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

Define filter as [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661792/servlet-name-inside-filter-mapping-of-web-xml-what-does-this-mean) connected to servlet:

> ```
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
>     <display-name>MyFilter</display-name>
>     <filter-class>com.xxx.yyy.zzz.MyFilter</filter-class>
> </filter>
>
> <filter-mapping>
>    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
>    <servlet-name>MyAction</servlet-name>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

Comment: So, where I can put the script 

'public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter { .....
'

Comment: @RidhoDwiDharmawan this is java code which is a part of your java application's source code.

Comment: Just put in web.xml or put in other file?

Comment: Put its full name in web.xml as `filter-class` value, as my examples

Comment: I create .java file with this content (code below) and then where I must put the file? `public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Contro .....`